# The pose of a model

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the pose when a woman covers her breasts with her hands (like for a photoshoot or movie)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a term that is coined lately for the pose is [handbra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handbra). (Also, *hand bra* or *hand-bra*.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[coy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/coy)**

> (Especially with reference to a woman) making a pretense of shyness or modesty that is intended to be alluring: *she treated him to a coy smile of invitation*

You might also consider the adjective **[demure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demure)**.  It can mean

> affectedly modest or prim; coy

It also can [mean](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/demure)

> Modest and reserved in manner or behavior.

Its application to a bashful nude would be a bit ironic.